# ifstream fails because I'm running out of file descriptors

Tags: c++, file-io, memory-leaks, fstream

I'm using Xcode5/clang on OSX 10.9.2.
My program starts acting up on

```
std::ifstream file(path);
if (!file.is_open())
    throw std::runtime_error("somethings wrong");
```

after a couple hundred (or thousand?) opening and closing files. 
When that happens, I cannot open any file anymore, neither with fstream nor with fopen(), which makes me think I ran out of file descriptors.
According to the documentation on ifstream, the file gets closed when the fstream object gets destroyed. All my fstream objects live on the stack, I never allocate any with new, so if my stack gets cleaned up properly, I don't have to call fstream::close() because when the object goes out of scope, the file is closed.

But apparently, I'm still leaking the file descriptors somewhere.

Questions:
1. Can I run out of file descriptors even if ifsteam objects are cleaned up as planned? Like, can file descriptors be re-used after they were closed, or are they gone forever once used and closed?
2. Is there a way I can possibly leak fstream objects, leaving them open, even if they all live on my stack?

Comment: Please provide more of your program to show the context. You aren't calling that recursively, are you?

Comment: Are you on Linux? You can check your file descriptors by looking around in /proc/<pid> where <pid> is the process id of you running program. Similar things are also available on other unixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found my problem.

I was not leaking fstream objects at all, but I have been leaking sqlite handles like crazy.
I found it through careful use of

```
lsof -p my_processes_pid | wc
```

lsof is a really helpful command!